# Merging PDF pages to single page, alternative to pdftk stamp function

Tags: linux, pdf, pdftk

I am trying to add page numbers to a PDF bundle.

Essentially the idea is to take 2 PDF pages, outputting one on top of the other,  creating a single PDF page output as described in tutorial: [Numbering PDF pages](http://cazencott.info/index.php/post/2015/04/30/Numbering-PDF-Pages)

The guide makes use of pdftk, which sadly is not available on my OS fedora 25. I was able to manage all using steps using pdfjam bundled scripts until running in to a command relying on following:

`pdftk stamp`

Is anybody able to share a solution to a foss, CLI alternative which provides similar behavior to the abovementioned pdftk command.

Thanks a bunch!
Jeffrey

Answer (score 1):

I use free (basic) version of PDFsam - PDF split-and-merge - for various pdf tasks. It needs java intalled. 
see https://pdfsam.org/